# OpenPopUpPage to go to new URL on close

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Currently my code is

```
OpenPopUpPage('mydialogurl', RefreshPage)
```

What do I need to change RefreshPage to be so that it moves to the new URL after my dialog closes?  So far I can only get it to go to the new URL immediately rather than after the dialog closes.

Comment: Can you post the source code for function `OpenPopUpPage`? It seems you should handle the dialog close handler and do a redirect from there.

Comment: I have this running in the onclick of an HTML button.  The refreshpage works upon close of the dialog but when I replace it with any other code it either goes to the link immediately (doesnt open the dialog) or it does not perform any function.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick...

```
OpenPopUpPage('mydialogurl', function() { window.location.href = "http://www.google.com" })
```

`OpenPopUpPage` has the following [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410825%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(url, callback, width, height)
```

The `callback` parameter takes any function you want called when the dialog is closed. I simply passed an anonymous function for the `callback` parameter that navigates to another page.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt do anything anymore...not even opening the popuppage.  For more background....I'm having this run in the onclick of an HTML button.

Comment: @thedude I'm unsure how to further troubleshoot your issue; are you suggesting it worked before but now does not? I've tested this on SP2010, 2013, and SharePoint Online and it works fine on all of those platforms. Are you sure you are entering the dialog URL correctly? Do you see any JavaScript errors in the browser console?

Comment: It works with RefreshPage as an action to the parent upon close. When I try to insert a function (anonymous or otherwise) the dialog will not pop up at all. I've tried it without passing a function but it will immediately go to the secondary URL (...OpenPopUpPage('mydialogurl',window.location.href='URL')....). I've also tried {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__redirect={'URL'})} which allows the dialog to pop up but goes to the URL before actions are completed in the dialog form. Replacing the callback seems to only work appropriately with RefreshPage.

Comment: If you're just trying to reload the page, you can use `document.location.reload();` inside of that anonymous function instead of the modal dialog `RefreshPage`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by adding `window.top.location.href="url"` in the dialog itself. For some reason the callback function in `openpopuppage` only worked with refresh page and trying to pass other functions would break it.

John-M: looks like he had the correct solution but for my form only the `window.top.location.href` function worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to get it working by setting up a [function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326072/javascript-function-pointer-assignment)

```
var f = function() { 
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com" 
}

OpenPopUpPage('mydialogurl', f );
```